# screencapture: cannot run two interactive screen captures at a time

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

```
        let imgPath: String = "\(self.tmpDir)captureRegion.png"

    //let screencapturePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForAuxiliaryExecutable("/usr/sbin/screencapture")! as String
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/sbin/screencapture"
    task.arguments = ["-i", "-r", imgPath]
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
```

when above code is executed, it show "screencapture: cannot run two interactive screen captures at a time" in output, and ScreenCapture not works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn off Sandbox or add `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-register.global-name` as the key and `com.apple.screencapture.interactive` as the value to the entitlements file.